# How do I replace the non-air blocks in a 5x5x5 area?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible for me to replace all non-air with stone blocks in a 5x5x5 box around where I am having the command executed? What is the command to do this?

Note: I believe that I can do it by replacing the air in the area with barriers, cloning it to another area, setting the area to stone, and then cloning only the barriers back from the area that they were cloned to, and setting all barriers in both zones to air. However, that is a very lengthy process, ad I need this command to run faster.

Answer (score 2):

have a 5*5 stone cube at spawn to clone to (assuming here you use 0 0 0 as the cube's coordinates)

```
/fill 0 0 0 4 4 4 stone                    // Fill temp area with stone
/clone x y z x2 y2 z2 0 0 0 filtered air   // clone all air blocks to temp area
/clone 0 0 0 4 4 4 x y z                   // clone temp area to destination
```

Answer (score -2):

This can be done, but it will require a lot of command blocks.
Basically there is no way to replace everything but air, unless you make a command block for every block except air.
This is similar to something Sethbling made, which you can check out [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6lonQHz394).

Comment: So, how would you go about doing it?  Just saying it's possible, without providing a method, isn't very useful.

Comment: The video i linked explains it in way more detail then i can using text.

Comment: Unfortunately, in order for an answer to be valid here at Arqade, it has to be encompassed in your answer, not just linked to.  That way, if the link ever goes down, your answer is still valid.  So please summarize the video's contents here.

Comment: My note explains a method that I have found and would work that requires few command blocks, I was asking about whether it was possible to do in _less_.