# Minecraft any way to use /clone to only replace air blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

As the title asks, Is there any way to use the clone command to only replace air blocks, such as breaking a floor and it being replaced by other blocks?

I know that this can be done using /fill, but I wanted to know if it can be done using /clone

Comment: Related but not dupe: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192830/how-do-i-replace-the-non-air-blocks-in-a-5x5x5-area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one command to do this and there's a bug report about that: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-126514

But what you **can** do is cloning your target area somewhere else, then cloning your source to the target and then cloning the temporary area back to the target using the "masked" mode of `/clone`. This first makes the target identical to the source and then places back all blocks except for air.

Comment: That doesn't work, it replaces the air aswell as other blocks

Comment: Oh right, it's basically the opposite in a way: It also doesn't copy air, but it does overwrite blocks if there are blocks in both the source and the target region. I'll change my answer.